# Jquery hover effects stop working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my website there are some ajax calls that filter product results. There are some effects applied on these products, which stop working after ajax call completes.

At the bottom of the page's code, there's the following:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    jQuery('.category-products-grid').on('mouseenter', '.item', function() {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }).on('mouseleave', '.item', function() {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    });

});
```

I've seen lots of similar posts about this issue, but none of the solutions suggested worked for me.

UPDATE
Here is the ajax call code. i didn't posted before because I don't believe it provides helpful information. There are many functions called int it and the code is too big to post here. The function that matters here is replaceProductsBlock(), and so I'll post it here:

```
var request = new Ajax.Request(url,
{
method:'GET',
parameters:params,
onSuccess: function(transport){

    ....

    replaceProductsBlock(response);

    ....

},
onFailure: function(){
    ....
}
});




replaceProductsBlock: function(response, need_scroll){

    var content = response.product_list;

    if (typeof(this.gan_static_navigation_url) != 'undefined' && this.gan_static_navigation_url){
        if ($$('div.col-main').length > 0){
            var col_main = $$('div.col-main')[0];
            col_main.innerHTML += '<div class="category-view">' + content + '</div>';
        }
        return;
    }

    var replace_toolbar = false;

    if($$('div.category-products').length > 0){
        element = $$('div.category-products')[0];
        if (element.select('div.toolbar').length == 0){
            replace_toolbar = true;         
        }
    }else if($$('div.col-main p.note-msg').length > 0){
        element = $$('div.col-main p.note-msg')[0];
    }else{
        return;
    }

    if (content && content.toElement){
        content = content.toElement();
    }else if (!Object.isElement(content)) {

      content = Object.toHTML(content);
      var tempElement = document.createElement('div');
      content.evalScripts.bind(content).defer();
      content = content.stripScripts();
      tempElement.innerHTML = content;

      el =  this.getElementsByClassName('category-products', tempElement);

      if (el.length > 0){
         content = el[0];
      }else{
         el = this.getElementsByClassName('note-msg', tempElement);
         if (el.length > 0){
            content = el[0];
            if (this.gan_shop_by_area == 1){
                var shop_by_content = Object.toHTML(response.navigation);        
                shop_by_content.evalScripts.bind(shop_by_content).defer();
                shop_by_content = shop_by_content.stripScripts();                
                var tempElement = document.createElement('div');
                tempElement.innerHTML = shop_by_content;
                var shop_by = this.getElementsByClassName('block-layered-nav', tempElement);
                if (shop_by.length > 0)
                {
                    shop_by = shop_by[0];
                    shop_by.id = 'gan_tmp_shop_by';
                    new Insertion.Before(element, shop_by);
                }   
            }
         }else{
            return;
         }
      }
    }
    element.parentNode.replaceChild(content, element);

    if (replace_toolbar && $$('div.category-products').length > 0){
        this.ganReplaceToolbal(response.product_list);        
    }   

    if (typeof(need_scroll) != 'undefined' && need_scroll){
        if ($$('div.category-products').length > 0){
            var category_products = $$('div.category-products')[0];
            category_products.scrollTo();
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Is `.item` and `.category-products-grid` elements present in DOM before ajax call ?

Comment: If the elements adding are `.category-products-grid` you'll have to bind the event to them after they are added or use event delegation for them.

Comment: are you sure .category-products-grid is the same before/after the ajax call?

Comment: Can we see what's happening inside the ajax success?

Comment: Off topic: If you're using `jQuery(function($) {` as your document.ready wrapper, you can use $ instead of 'jQuery' inside it.

Comment: You've not provided enough information to be able to see what is wrong. What are you doing inside the functions? What is the AJAX code you are doing. Take a look at the console in your browser's developer tools. There may be an error message there that could help you.

Comment: @Ani yes, the elements are present before the ajax call.

Comment: @alberto2000 the .category-products-grid is the same. The items inside it are the ones tha change. The class names and structure remains tha same. The content changes.

Comment: @kayen I updated the question and posted more information about the ajax call

Comment: @rjmunro, there are no errors on firebug console. You can see more information about the ajax call on the ypdated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing and failing again and again to solve this (used jquery live(), one(), livequery() and many many more..) I finally found a solution.

It's described in this article:
[Re-binding jQuery Events on AJAX Callbacks](http://jetlogs.org/2009/01/29/re-binding-jquery-events-on-ajax-callbacks/)

The code I used looks something like this:

```
function initBinding(){
    jQuery('.category-products-grid > .item').hover(function() {
        ...
        ...
    }, function() {
        ...
        ...
    });
}



var request = new Ajax.Request(url,
{
    ...
    ...
    onSuccess: function(transport){
        initBinding();
    }
});
```

Comment: Will you please help me in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092406/zooming-stopped-working-after-media-phtml-reloaded-with-ajax-in-magento